# Enable IPv6 IP forwarding on Windows by default

Tags: windows, routing, ipv6, forwarding, wireguard

I'm running Wireguard on a Windows server, connected to multiple peers.

Peer A <-> Server <-> Peer B

In order to allow peers to ping each other (Peer A wants to reach Peer B), IP routing/forwarding needs to be enabled.

This can be achieved quite easily for IPv4 by enabling IPEnableRouter in registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`

For IPv6, however, I was not able to find a *global* switch to enable IP forwarding. It is easily possible to enable it for a specific interface:

`netsh interface ipv6 set interface 14 forwarding=enabled`

However, this will not help as Wireguard deletes and recreates the interface, so the forwarding state is lost on every re-/disconnect.

One can also do `Set-NetIPInterface -Forwarding Enabled` via PowerShell and have all interfaces set to forwarding=enabled, but like the previous approach this will only cover existing interfaces.

**So, is there an option to have IPv6 forwarding enabled "by default", i.e. for new interfaces?**

On Linux, I would just have to do `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding=1` or `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding=1`, so essentially I'm looking for a Windows equivalent to that.